# Linphone and python3

Tags: python, linphone

I have linphone installed for python2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine.

But now I want to move to python3.5 and I am having problems.
https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/getting_started.html#installing-the-python-module
only indicates the instructions to install it for python2.7
Anyone has tried this?
In parallel I am trying to build the libraries for linphone desktop from scratch but it is a bit of a nightmare
Thanks so much
Ester

Comment: If you take a look at the [linphone PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/linphone/), under the section "Programming Language", towards the bottom, you'll see the project only currently supports python2.7

Comment: Damm it! Thanks Jack

Comment: Yes, damn it, looks like you'll have to stick with Python 2.7 for the time being :( !